# Prove that $C(S,F)$ is a subspace of $G(S,F)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a nonempty set and $F$ a field. Let $C(S,F)$ denote the set of all functions $f \in G(S,F)$ such that $f(s) = 0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$. Prove that $C(S,F)$ is a subspace of $G(S,F)$.

I'm trying to show that $cf \in C(S,F)$ for some $ c \in F$, where $f(s) = 0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$. But if $c=0$, we have that $cf=0$ for all elements of $S$. I was wondering how this still fits the property of the subspace $C$ where $f(s)=0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$.

Comment: Can you define $G(S,F)$?

Comment: $G(S,F)$ is the set of all functions from a nonempty set $S$ to a field $F$.

Comment: Alright, just making sure. Let's rephrase the property ``$f(s)=0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$.'' For $f\in G(S,F)$, we can define $N_f=\{s\in S:f(s)\neq 0\}$. Then $C(S,F)=\{f\in G(S,F):|N_f|<\infty\}$. In your case, if $c=0$, then $N_{cf}=\varnothing$ and certainly $|\varnothing|=0<\infty$, so $cf\in C(S,F)$.

Comment: When doing the proof, do I have to specify both cases? So, I have to show that in both cases, where $c=0$ and $c \ne 0$, $cf = 0$ for all but a finite number of elements of $S$?

Comment: I think the easiest way to argue this is that for any $c\in F$ and $f\in G(S,F)$, then $N_{cf}\subseteq N_f$. So if $|N_f|<\infty$, then certainly $|N_{cf}|<\infty$.

Comment: Similarly, when trying to show that $C(S,F)$ is closed under addition, it's probably easiest to show that $N_{f+g}\subseteq N_f\cup N_g$ for any $f,g\in G(S,F)$.